# is box-shadow (CSS3) really not ready to use? (according to "CAN I USE")

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I want you to help me, I am currently making a website, I am building that website on HTML5 and CSS3 technology, every feature I'd like to use I check it first in "[CAN I USE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)", the technology I use most is box-shadow, and I already made some great things with it but, I have a doubt about the percentage of browser that don't support that technology, the percentage of browser that do not support box-shadow is around 17.12%, and if you see the conclusions (show options => other options => show conclusions) they say that that feature isn't ready yet because they are "Waiting for Opera Mini 5.0-6.0 to expire", I personally think that the best that we can do in order to make people update their browsers is not support older browser, but ...

am I right thinking like this?

will I have bad consecuences if I don't support older browsers?

is worth to work twice just to support older browsers?

should I still working with box-shadow?

Comment: It's perfectly ready to use; just don't make it a *necessity* of your website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always....

## [Progressive Enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/).

Build your site so it works well for **everybody regardless of their browser settings and capabilities**. Then add features that enhance the experience but don't cause the site to break for those who cannot take advantage of that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS3 elements(shadow, rounded corners,...) will not work in older browsers. That's a fact, but you can still use them as the mentioned browsers simply ignore this attribute.

Best way would be that the design of the website doesn't rely on the shadow and other effects, but only to enhance it.

Also take into account the market share of the browsers that don't use these elements. Opera's got a tiny share on the desktop market, and a little bigger on mobile devices, but in no case is a major player. Pre 8 Internet Explorer will give you the most headaches...

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with John Conde,

Do you want to make a website to teach a lesson to people who still use old browsers?
Or are you seeking more visitors?

Start with a simple design that everybody could use, and then improve it for modern browsers while keeping old browsers in mind.